# OSGi on JBoss EAP 6

Tags: java, jboss, osgi, wildfly

I have an existing ear application that makes no use of OSGi in any way running on a jboss server that currently has no OSGi configured.

Now I need to plug in a number of external libraries that use OSGi (declaratively!) for service setup so I need to enable the OSGi container in the configuration and somehow make my ear application aware of them.

To enable the OSGi container, I copied the relevant (or so I hope) parts of the example configuration file: `standalone-osgi-only.xml` (including the logger) but currently I see no additional output when loading the server (subsystem is set to eager).

I have moved the bundles into a custom folder in the "bundles" directory but am not sure if this is the correct place for them.

Additionally I am not sure how to configure my ear file to "see" the bundles. Do I need to add something to the `jboss-app.xml` or `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` or can it simply see all the OSGi bundles?

**UPDATE**

The code in the ear file does not actually need access to any of the OSGi services, it needs access to a specific class that is in one of the libraries, let's call it "MyClass". So the code in the ear file does:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
myClass.doSomething();
```

The class MyClass however uses a ton of OSGi-managed services to accomplish the task in doSomething().

I have loaded all the libraries in a test OSGi environment and the test runs ok.

**UPDATE 2**

Ok, I have successfully enabled OSGi on the jboss server by adding the following to standalone.xml:

```
<extensions>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.configadmin"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.osgi"/>
</extensions>
```

And

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:configadmin:1.0">
        <configuration pid="org.apache.felix.webconsole.internal.servlet.OsgiManager">
            <property name="manager.root" value="jboss-osgi"/>
        </configuration>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:osgi:1.2" activation="eager">
        <properties>
            <property name="org.jboss.osgi.system.modules.extra">
                org.apache.log4j
            </property>
            <property name="org.osgi.framework.startlevel.beginning">
                1
            </property>
            <property name="org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra">
                org.apache.log4j;version=1.2
            </property>
        </properties>
        <capabilities>
            <capability name="javax.servlet.api:v25"/>
            <capability name="javax.transaction.api"/>
            <capability name="javax.xml.bind.api"/>
            <capability name="javax.validation.api2"/>
            <capability name="org.apache.felix.log" startlevel="1"/>
            <capability name="org.jboss.osgi.logging" startlevel="1"/>
            <capability name="org.apache.felix.configadmin" startlevel="1"/>
            <capability name="org.jboss.as.osgi.configadmin" startlevel="1"/>
        </capabilities>
    </subsystem>
```

On the first try I was getting WARN logs like this:

```
[org.jboss.as.osgi] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS011910: Cannot resolve requirements: 
    [XPackageRequirement[atts={osgi.wiring.package=javax.xml.bind.annotation},
    [mybundle:1.0.0]]]
```

Even though these were warnings, they would prevent the application from booting, to fix this I added the necessary "root" dependencies (so to speak) by adjusting the "capabilities" bit of the OSGi subsystem. I have added the module javax.xml.bind.api which contains all the JAXB stuff that the frameworks need and I have installed a new module javax.validation.api2 which basically contains version 1.1 (needed by the frameworks) instead of the provided-by-default version 1.0.

In my application.ear file I have added the 10 or so jars containing the OSGi bundles to the root folder. I get the following log for each jar inside the ear: `org.jboss.osgi.framework] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBOSGI011001: Bundle installed: mybundle`

So basically everything looks OK from the OSGi perspective **but** my actual application still doesn't see the libraries. The ear looks like this:

- META-INF

  - application.xml
- mybundle1.jar
- mybundle2.jar
- mybundle3.jar
- MyEJB.jar

The application.xml dutifully contains the ejb entry for MyEJB.jar, however the EJB code can not actually see the code of the bundles, it will throw ClassNotFoundException.

If I move all my bundles to the `lib` folder inside the ear file, my EJB code will find the classes, but no OSGi magic happens so the jars don't find one another.

So now I'm trying to figure out how to have the OSGi modules loaded **and** visible for my EJB.

**UPDATE 3**

I have added all the bundles to the `META-INF/application.xml` file as "java" modules, however this does something weird.

The package `MyEJB` has a direct code dependency to say `bundle1` but **not** to any other bundles. Now `bundle1` in turn has a code dependency to other bundles and those bundles to yet other bundles etc.

With the jars in my application.xml, it no longer throws an exception that it can not find the class in `bundle1` (yay!) buuut...now I get a ClassNotFoundException from `bundle2` which is referenced by `bundle1`...

Comment: There are lot of things involved here. Are you exporting the services that you are referencing?. Are you registering your services ?. Are you registering them properly?.

Comment: I have updated the original question.

Comment: "A lot of things involved here"... you can say that again. This is not so much an SO question as a consulting engagement.

Comment: @NeilBartlett I tried to be thorough in documenting the steps I have already taken. But in the end it still boils down to a simple question: how to have a "plain EE" project use OSGi-bundles in a JBoss environment.

Comment: @nablex Fair enough. I suppose that getting an answer depends on finding somebody familiar with both technologies.

Answer (score 3):

JBoss OSGi [has currently no maintainer](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/238007). It is not supported in EAP 6 and no longer part of WildFly AS. I suggest you find a different way to run OSGi. Be it Aries, Gemini or running a full OSGi container in your EAR.

Comment: Hmm, that is bad. The frameworks currently support OSGi or SPI. OSGi is no longer supported and SPI is dead in the module system (afaik), so what is the jboss equivalent to services? Can I add some configuration files that will do OSGi-like service stuff?

Comment: I don't know what you mean with SPI in this context. I would try to avoid depending on any JBoss internal APi as they are all unsupported and subject to change.

Comment: SPI as in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html. The frameworks were designed to (currently) work in three different ways: SPI, OSGi or manual configuration. If jboss has a custom service system that can be tacked on with configuration files, I would be happy to add those to the frameworks as well.

Comment: JBoss has it's own [Modular Service Container](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/MSC/Home) but I didn't think you want to use this. AFAIK it's internal API and not even exported to the deployments.